# Javascript Replace with parameters

Tags: javascript, frontend, markdown

So I'm making a markdown editor, and I want some function like `"This is *italics*".replace("*$1*","<i>$1</i>");`

Any easy way to do this? (Client Side, this'll be hosted on Github Pages or something, so a random npm package probably won't help)

Edit: An equal number of people have upvoted and downvoted this. It would help if you tell me why you downvoted.

Comment: Please add more examples of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Try `"this is *italics*".replace(/\B(\*)(.+)(\*)\B/,"<i>$2</i>")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** `'This is *italics*'.replace(/\*(.+)\*/, '<i>$1</i>');`

---

**Explanation:** Using [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is the easiest way to go about this, specifically the [grouping section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references).
Let's strip down `/\*(.+)\*/`:

1. The starting and ending `/` are defining that the thing in between is actually a `RegExp`
2. We need to check for asterisks at the start and at the end, [but * is a quantity selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers) in the RegExp, therefore we need to escape them using a `\` (basically saying "hey, the next chracter is not an actual selector, but something literal")
3. Next we need to specify that we need to check for [any character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes) between those asterisks (that's the `.`), appearing more than once (that's the `+`)
4. Finally we need to `group` this and tell the RegExp that what we want to remember is the thing between the asterisks and not the whole thing, that's where the `parenthesis` come to action.
5. Using those parenthesis, we can do `$n` (where `n` is the matched quantity number, in this case `1`) in the replacing string to replace for the matching group

Comment: Thanks. I usually find RegExp very confusing, but your explanation really helped me understand it. :)